# RabbitMQ bind exchange to exchange in bash

Tags: bash, docker, rabbitmq, queue, rabbitmq-exchange

I would like to bind an `exchange` to another `exchange` via a `bash` script (what I plan to use within a Dockerfile).

As simple code (like `JS`) it is fine, working perfectly, but I would like to use plain `bash` script for it, if it is possible.

The part of the `JS` code, what I would like to have but in `bash`:

```
// ...
await ch1.assertExchange('test-exchange', 'headers');
await ch1.assertExchange('another-exchange', 'headers');
await ch1.bindExchange('test-exchange', 'another-exchange','',{
      'x-match':'all',
      target: 'pay-flow'
});
// ...
```

When I run the `JS` code, then it is fine. I got the following results in RabbitMQ:

```bash
bash-5.1# rabbitmqadmin -u guest -p guest list bindings
+-----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|     source      |      destination      |      routing_key      |
+-----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|                 | test-queue            | test-queue            |
| test-exchange   | test-queue            |                       |
| test-exchange   | another-exchange      |                       |
+-----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

What I tried in bash:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
rabbitmqadmin -u guest -p guest declare binding source=test-exchange destination=another-exchange
```

Then I got the message of:

```bash
** Not found: /api/bindings/%2F/e/test-exchange/q/another-exchange
```

By the `CLI/rabbitmqadmin documentation` it seems, I am supposed to (or able only to) bind an `exchange` with a `queue`.

Anyone has any idea, how to solve it? (Maybe write the binder code in python and run it from the bash script?) Are there any kind of cli tool what capable to do it?

Comment: You say you want this so you can do it in a Dockerfile; but a Docker image build can't normally connect to other containers or resources, and it'd be very possible to run the same image against a different RabbitMQ broker without rebuilding it.  Does it make more sense to do this setup as part of your application startup, in a non-Docker-specific way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the command's help:

```
$ rabbitmqadmin help subcommands | grep -F 'declare binding'
  declare binding source=... destination=... [destination_type=... routing_key=... arguments=...]
```

This is the correct set of arguments:

```
rabbitmqadmin -u guest -p guest declare binding source=test-exchange destination=another-exchange destination_type=exchange
```

Of course, before you run the above command the two exchanges must exist.

Tested as follows:

```
$ rabbitmqadmin declare exchange name=test-exchange type=direct
exchange declared

$ rabbitmqadmin declare exchange name=test-exchange-2 type=direct
exchange declared

$ rabbitmqadmin declare binding source=test-exchange destination=test-exchange-2 destination_type=exchange
binding declared
```

Comment: Thank you! The `destination_type` parameter immediately solved my problem.